# Available space on disk array, running Raid-Z1?

Tags: raid, zfs

I just installed NexentaStor Open Source on a Dell R510.

I created a Raid-Z1 with 4 x 2TB disks. No Spare disks configured.

NexentaStor now tells me the the Datasat have 7,35TB free space, I was expecting aboutn 5,5 TB, because of the n-1 rule.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What does `zpool status` show? Sounds like you created something wrong...

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your `Data Management` -> `Data Sets` screen in the NexentaStor interface?

Comment: ewwhite: Here you go. Data Set: http://postimage.org/image/6lygl5zdz/ Disks: http://postimage.org/image/szaslpppj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `zpool list` will show the *RAW* space available to the pool (sum of disks).

Your `zfs list` will show the amount of usable post-RAID redundancy space available.

Of course, `du` and `ls` will show different values, too...

Comment: disk manufacturers use base-10 when sizing disks, while computers use base-2.  So that 2TB HDD as labeled on the box, is likely to be recognized by your OS as 1.83 TB. `4 * 1.83 = 7.32`, which is pretty close.  Keep in mind that ZFS doesn't reserve whole disks for parity, instead all the disks are stripes and it's the data for which parity is calculated.